# Simple form in rails can't post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I use simple form in rails. After submit data. the page always return to application_form#new, and data can't be saved in db. Why?

### log

```
Started POST "/application_forms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-25 19:23:28 +0800
Processing by ApplicationFormsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yypWFcsXbdSVtp3WXUZKvstzHWsV0OOpLoGSxO1ldJ0=", "application_form"=>{"student_name"=>"somebody", ...... ,"application_type"=>"b"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  Rendered application_forms/_form.html.erb (24.0ms)
  Rendered application_forms/new.html.erb within layouts/application (25.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 52.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

### View

```
<%= simple_form_for @application_form, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>
  <%= f.input :student_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit', :class => 'btn-large btn-primary'%>

<% end %>
```

---

### Controller

```
 def create

    @application_form = ApplicationForm.new(params[:application_form])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @application_form.save
        format.html { redirect_to @application_form, :notice => 'Submit ok.' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Seems that the problem is in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly `@application_form.save` is failing.  If I had to guess, I'd guess you've got a validation on your model that's failing.  This happens to me occasionally when I've written a good model, including all the validations I will want, but then I'm just starting to put together a form and I forget to include all the fields that need to be there.

One way to check this is to open up

```
rails console
```

and try something like this:

```
@application_form = ApplicationForm.new(:student_name => "student")
@application_form.save
```

This will do pretty much exactly what your form is doing, and should tell you what the problem is when you try to save.

My guess is that you've also forgotten to include flash messages in your layout file.  Usually you'll see some sort of error message in your flash when `save` fails.  Since it seems like you're using Twitter Bootstrap (just guessing from the `form-horizontal` class on your form view), assuming your using the [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem, you can just add  `<%= bootstrap_flash %>` to either your view or your template.

Comment: Thanks, it's validates problem.