# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Create method has unexpected response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently working through Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training via lynda.com.  I have searched SO thoroughly and have not found an answer that I can successfully apply to my issue.  I am new to Rails (and software development) and my limited knowledge could hinder my search skills.

The POST issued by the from does not create the new subject record and expectedly renders new, but I am not sure why.  Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750558/simple-form-in-rails-cant-post-data) I was able to insert a subject record successfully using the console with @subject.save command.  I am not sure how to debug this type of form POST.  Does anyone see a problem with the code or output? (Apologies for the unsuccessful syntax highlighting.)

I have in my controller:

```
def index
  @subjects = Subject.sorted
end

def new
  @subject = Subject.new({:name => "Default"})
end

def create
  @subject = Subject.new(params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :position, :visible))
  if @subject.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

Entries in the routes.rb file:

```
root "demo#index"

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Output from the POST to create a subject:

```
Started POST "/subjects/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 21:24:11 -0500
Processing by SubjectsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NZInczd9IeLm8n+nX0vecRlVCTTAwdbclqleTKUqeEc=", 
"subject"=>{"name"=>"Test Subject", "position"=>"8", "visible"=>"false"}, "commit"=>"Create Subject"}
Rendered subjects/new.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Rake routes output:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
root GET      /                                      demo#index
     GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="subjects new">
   <h2>Create Subject</h2>

  <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'new'}) do |f| %>

<table summary="Subject form fields">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Visible</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
</div>
```

Comment: as the code states, the new view gets rendered if the @subject did not save. It likely has a validation error, or you have a callback in your model that is preventing a save.

Comment: The model does not contain any callbacks and there are not validates in the controller.  All columns on the table are nullable or have a default value. Would the validation error be visible in the POST output?

Comment: no it would not. Please add your model code to the question.

Comment: oh wait..... I see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit in this situation was in the new.html.erb view (that I had not originally included in my question).  It should send the post to the 'create' action.

```
{:action=> 'create'}
```

I would suggest reading the guide linked in @sevenseacat's answer as it illustrates what I'm sure is a more robust approach to routing and I found very informative.

Comment: I do still very strongly recommend disabling the catch-all route and instead using restful routing. But in the end, I'm glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your routing is completely incorrect.

You're building a normal RESTful controller (index, new, create, etc.) and not pairing it with RESTful routing. So submitting a form post for a new Subject should go to the `create` action of your controller - it isn't. It's going to the `new` action.

Have a read over this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

In short, you need to declare `resources :projects` in your routes file. And please, please, remove that catch-all route - it's downright harmful.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, but unfortunately, it was an unanswerable question.  The bug lay in the new.html.erb code that I did not include in the question.  I'm not sure the etiquette for this situation.

Comment: @markN Best thing to do is provide the additional information in the question, and add your answer. Who knows, someone else may have the same problem in the future.